# Circle and a line contains exactly two points

Tags: geometry

Let $\{P, L,d\}$ be a metric geometry, where $P$ is the set of points, $L$ set of lines and $d$ is the metric. Let $q\in P$, $l\in L$ with $q \in l$, and let $C$ be a circle with center $q$. Prove that $l\cap C$ contains exactly two points.

How can I prove this? The wording doesn't really make sense to me because how can $l\cap C$ contain exactly two points?

Comment: Hint: draw a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $q$ is the center of $C$, and $l$ passes through $q$, then $l$ is a diameter, so in the common planar geometry the fact is pretty obvious: every diameter intersects a circle in two distinct points.

For other geometries, I guess it might depend on your definition of a circle. If a circle is the set of points which are at the same non-zero distance from the center, then in spherical geometry you could choose that radius to be half the circumference of the sphere. Then the circle would contain only of a single point, antipodal to the center, and the statement would be false. So have a close look at your definition of a circle before you start prooving this for general metric spaces.